# Profiling JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, profiling

Is there any way to profile JavaScript program to find out the number of times each function is invoked in the program?

Also, I want to see how much percentage of total execution time is spent on introducing inline cache in the program. 
I am aware of v8 profiling tools which gives output similar to https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAKoU.png. What does the 
percentage in brackets refer to? Does IC Miss(24.3%) means that 24.3% of the total execution time is spent on 
inline caching? Then why does these percentages do not sum up to 100%.

Comment: What is the environment? (browser, server, etc?) Did you look at the profile tab in the Developer Consoles in your browse?